# Show that the sequence $x_{n+1} = \frac12(x_n+ \sqrt{x_n})$ converges and determine the limit.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, epsilon-delta

> Let $x_1=3$ and $x_{n+1} = \frac12(x_n+ \sqrt{x_n})$. Show that the sequence converges and determine the limit.

How should I formulate this in order to use $\varepsilon - \delta$? I assume that's what they would want me to use? I found
$$x_2 = \frac12(3+\sqrt{3})= \frac{3+\sqrt{3}}{2},$$
but this doesn't seem to lead to anywhere.

Comment: If $x_n$ converges then you may apply the limit on both sides of your recurrence relation for $n\to +\infty$

Comment: $\varepsilon,\delta$ is one method, but it has the disadvantage of requiring knowledge (or at least an educated guess) of the limit ahead of time. Here's another way to show a sequence converges: if $(x_n)$ is bounded below and decreasing, it converges (similarly for bounded above and increasing). Then if you know the limit exists, say it equals $L$, you can use the recursion to find it.

Comment: This will give you a second order equation in $l$ (the limit to which the sequence converges if it converges). The positive solution is what you are looking for.

Comment: With problems like this its useful to experiment a bit, which will often show you how what to do. Compute the numerical value of $x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$. Do you see a trend? Try to prove what you observe.

Comment: @Integrand I could try to use induction to prove that the sequence is decreasing, but how would I show that it's bounded below?

Comment: It's bounded below by $0$

Comment: Ah, indeed. Suddenly that seems quite obvious. :D

Comment: @Winther is there a clean way to cut through the thicket of nested radicals?

Comment: @Integrand Can't imagine that. The suggestion was simply to compute things numerically to get an idea of how to approach it (though I see you already pointed this out above).

Answer (score 3):

*Another hint*. Look at the function $f(x)=\frac{x+\sqrt{x}}{2}$ where $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$. Find that $f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4\sqrt{x}}>0, x>0$. Conclude that $f(x)$ is ascending for $x>0$. Check that $x_1>x_2$, then $x_2=f(x_1)\geq f(x_2)=x_3$, leading to $x_1>x_2\geq x_3$. And so on, by induction $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is monotone descending and bounded (say by $0$), thus [the limit exists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem). It should be one of the solutions of $L=\frac{L+\sqrt{L}}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Prove by induction: for all $n$, $x_n \ge 1$ and $x_{n+1} \le x_n$. Conclude that $x_n$ converges to $L \ge 1$. Find $L$.

Answer (score 2):

> Let $x_1=3$ and $x_{n+1} = \frac12(x_n+ \sqrt{x_n})$. Show that the sequence converges and determine the limit.

[image]
From the graph, $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=1$ if one starts from $x=3$ because choosing $x=1$ makes one stick at $x=1$ in the graph.